# R - How to calculate value differences between dates with heterogeneous number of rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My data look like the following example.

`# A tibble: 18 x 4
    DATE       AUTHOR PRODUCT  SALES
   <dttm>      <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>
 1 2019-11-27  James  B          80
 2 2019-11-28  James  B         100
 3 2019-11-27  James  A          80
 4 2019-11-28  James  A         100
 5 2019-11-26  Frank  B          70
 6 2019-11-27  Frank  B          75
 7 2019-11-28  Frank  B          65
 8 2019-11-26  Frank  A          70
 9 2019-11-27  Frank  A          75
10 2019-11-28  Frank  A          65
11 2019-11-25  Mary   A         100
12 2019-11-26  Mary   A          80
13 2019-11-27  Mary   A          95
14 2019-11-28  Mary   A         110
15 2019-11-25  Mary   B         100
16 2019-11-26  Mary   B          80
17 2019-11-27  Mary   B          95
18 2019-11-28  Mary   B         110`

I would like to add a "DIFF" column where the difference over day for SALES is calculated grouping by AUTHOR. My issues here are the following:

- I have a different number of rows for every AUTHOR.
- The same DATE could be repeated for some AUTHORS to report different information (in this example is PRODUCT), but the value for SALES will always remain the same, since it only depends on the DATE and the AUTHOR.
- I have to keep every row in the dataset because every row contains specific information, so I can not just drop the rows where DATE is a duplicated.
- Ideally I would implement the whole with a loop function in my script.

My desired outcome would be:

`# A tibble: 18 x 4
    DATE       AUTHOR PRODUCT  SALES DIFF
   <dttm>      <chr>  <chr>   <dbl> 
 1 2019-11-27  James  B          80

 2 2019-11-28  James  B         100   20
 3 2019-11-27  James  A          80
 4 2019-11-28  James  A         100   20
 5 2019-11-26  Frank  B          70
 6 2019-11-27  Frank  B          75   5
 7 2019-11-28  Frank  B          65  -10
 8 2019-11-26  Frank  A          70
 9 2019-11-27  Frank  A          75   5
10 2019-11-28  Frank  A          65  -10
11 2019-11-25  Mary   A         100
12 2019-11-26  Mary   A          80  -20
13 2019-11-27  Mary   A          95   15
14 2019-11-28  Mary   A         110   15
15 2019-11-25  Mary   B         100
16 2019-11-26  Mary   B          80  -20
17 2019-11-27  Mary   B          95   15
18 2019-11-28  Mary   B         110   15`

I tried different things with `dplyr` and `mutate` but nothing seemed to work. Anyone has suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lag` to subtract previous value by group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  group_by(AUTHOR, PRODUCT) %>%  mutate(diff = SALES - lag(SALES))

#   DATE       AUTHOR PRODUCT SALES  diff
#   <fct>      <fct>  <fct>   <int> <int>
# 1 2019-11-27 James  B          80    NA
# 2 2019-11-28 James  B         100    20
# 3 2019-11-27 James  A          80    NA
# 4 2019-11-28 James  A         100    20
# 5 2019-11-26 Frank  B          70    NA
# 6 2019-11-27 Frank  B          75     5
# 7 2019-11-28 Frank  B          65   -10
# 8 2019-11-26 Frank  A          70    NA
# 9 2019-11-27 Frank  A          75     5
#10 2019-11-28 Frank  A          65   -10
#11 2019-11-25 Mary   A         100    NA
#12 2019-11-26 Mary   A          80   -20
#13 2019-11-27 Mary   A          95    15
#14 2019-11-28 Mary   A         110    15
#15 2019-11-25 Mary   B         100    NA
#16 2019-11-26 Mary   B          80   -20
#17 2019-11-27 Mary   B          95    15
#18 2019-11-28 Mary   B         110    15
```

Or using `diff`

```
df %>%  group_by(AUTHOR, PRODUCT) %>%  mutate(diff = c(NA, diff(SALES)))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("2019-11-25", 
"2019-11-26", "2019-11-27", "2019-11-28"), class = "factor"), 
AUTHOR = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Frank", 
"James", "Mary"), class = "factor"), PRODUCT = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), SALES = c(80L, 
100L, 80L, 100L, 70L, 75L, 65L, 70L, 75L, 65L, 100L, 80L, 
95L, 110L, 100L, 80L, 95L, 110L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, diff :=  SALES - shift(SALES), .(AUTHOR, PRODUCT)][]
```